# How do you update a dictionary value that is a set?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to create a function that will track IP assignments for unique mac addresses.
I plan on doing this by creating a dictionary that uses the MAC + Location as the key, and the value will be a set() as a way of tracking unique IP assignments per mac address.

I can't seem to append new IP addresses to the set() dictionary value though using the below:

**Function:**

```
def trackmac(ip, location, mac):
    if ip_tracker.get(f'{mac} {location}') == None:
        ip_tracker[f'{mac} {location}'] = set((ip,))
        print(f'[!] First ip entry: {ip}')
    elif ip_tracker.get(f'{mac} {location}') != None:
        print('[!] not first ip entry')
        update_iplist = ip_tracker.get(f'{mac} {location}')
        ip_tracker[f'{mac} {location}'] = update_iplist.add(ip)
```

**Output:**

Once I test the function the first time the key (MAC + Location) has been seen it creates a set and adds the IP address.

```
>>> trackmac('192.168.1.10', 'home', 'AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA')
[!] First ip entry: 192.168.1.10
>>> print(ip_tracker)
{'AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA home': {'192.168.1.10'}}
>>> trackmac('192.168.1.11', 'home', 'BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB')
[!] First ip entry: 192.168.1.11
>>> print(ip_tracker)
{'AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA home': {'192.168.1.10'}, 'BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB home': {'192.168.1.11'}}
```

**Error:**

The second time it returns the value of that key as None rather than adding the new IP address to the set() value.

```
>>> trackmac('192.168.1.12', 'home', 'BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB')
[!] not first ip entry
>>> print(ip_tracker)
{'AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA home': {'192.168.1.10'}, 'BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB home': None}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do you update a dictionary value that is a set in Python?

```
my_dict[key_with_set].add(my_value)
```

your issue is the fact that `set.add` returns `None`, this line `ip_tracker[f'{mac} {location}'] = update_iplist.add(ip)` will make `ip_tracker[f'{mac} {location}']` to be equal with `None` since `update_iplist.add(ip)` returns `None`

you can use:

```
def trackmac(ip, location, mac):
    ip_tracker.setdefault(f'{mac} {location}', set()).add(ip)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I blame the lock down for not being able to resolve this myself

Answer (score 1):

The `set.add` method modifies the set in-place and returns `None`, so your:

```
ip_tracker[f'{mac} {location}'] = update_iplist.add(ip)
```

would override the value of that key with `None`.

You can instead use the `dict.setdefault` method to initialize each new key with an empty set, and then call the `set.add` method to add an IP to it:

```
def trackmac(ip, location, mac):
    ip_tracker.setdefault(f'{mac} {location}', set()).add(ip)
```

Answer (score 1):

The culprits are these lines:

```
update_iplist = ip_tracker.get(f'{mac} {location}')
ip_tracker[f'{mac} {location}'] = update_iplist.add(ip)
```

When you call `update_iplist.add(ip)` on the set of IP addresses, the return value of the function `add()` is `None`, because it only has a side effect of adding your new IP address to the set. The assignment then overwrites the value stored in the dictionary with `None`.
The wrong assumption here is that the `add()` function actually returns the set, when in truth it doesn't.

You can easily fix it by replacing those two lines as follows:

```py
ip_tracker[f'{mac} {location}'].add(ip)
```

This is safe to do because you already checked that the key exists in the dictionary.

Hope this helps